# Getting error installing ruby 1.9.2-p320 using RVM

Tags: rvm, fedora, ruby-1.9.2

I am running Fedora 18 on x86-64 architecture. I am able to install Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM. But, when I try to install Ruby 1.9.2, it's giving me following error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p320 to /home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracted to /home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #compiling
Error running 'make', please read /home/abhay/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Following is the content of make.log file:

```
compiling bigdecimal
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/bigdecimal'
gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -I../.././ext/bigdecimal -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/include    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC  -o bigdecimal.o -c bigdecimal.c
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so bigdecimal.o -L. -L../.. -L/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
/usr/bin/mkdir -p ../../.ext/common/bigdecimal
cp ../.././ext/bigdecimal/lib/bigdecimal/newton.rb ../../.ext/common/bigdecimal
cp ../.././ext/bigdecimal/lib/bigdecimal/math.rb ../../.ext/common/bigdecimal
cp ../.././ext/bigdecimal/lib/bigdecimal/jacobian.rb ../../.ext/common/bigdecimal
cp ../.././ext/bigdecimal/lib/bigdecimal/ludcmp.rb ../../.ext/common/bigdecimal
cp ../.././ext/bigdecimal/lib/bigdecimal/util.rb ../../.ext/common/bigdecimal
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/bigdecimal'
compiling continuation
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/continuation'
gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -I../.././ext/continuation -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/include    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC  -o continuation.o -c continuation.c
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/continuation.so continuation.o -L. -L../.. -L/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/continuation'
compiling coverage
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/coverage'
gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -I../.././ext/coverage -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/include    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC  -o coverage.o -c coverage.c
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/coverage.so coverage.o -L. -L../.. -L/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -lruby  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/coverage'
compiling curses
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/curses'
gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -I../.././ext/curses -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\" -I/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/include    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC  -o curses.o -c curses.c
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/curses.so curses.o -L. -L../.. -L/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -lruby -lncursesw -ltinfo  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
curses.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/curses.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/abhay/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320/ext/curses'
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as up on Fedora as I once was, but on my Debian x86_64 machine this line is slightly different. In that, yours is calling for `libncursesw` and mine calls for `libncurses`; these two libraries are reasonably source-compatible, but may cause slight rendering differences based on your locale settings. See top line of code block below for how my machine called gcc to compile curses.so to curses.o versus yours on the bottom line:

```
gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/curses.so curses.o -L. -L../.. -L. -L/home/schade/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/schade/.rvm/usr/lib -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/schade/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/home/schade/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -lruby -lncurses -ltinfo  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc

gcc -shared -o ../../.ext/x86_64-linux/curses.so curses.o -L. -L../.. -L/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R/home/abhay/.rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic   -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -L/home/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib -lruby -lncursesw -ltinfo  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
```

As you can see other than our username, the only difference is `-lncurses` versus `-lncursesw`.

If you can manage without unicode support, perhaps a similar fix to the solution for this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/416147/fedora-16-failed-to-install-scion-browser-with-cabal) would solve this issue for you.